# the SQLTransactionCallback was null or threw an exception phonegap

Tags: php, ajax, cordova, web-sql, phonegap-desktop-app

Hi all out attempt by internal DB ajax call to the external DB but I have this error, the first ajax is to check for connection to the database (for security I remove the url requests )

```
$.post( "xxxxxxxx", function( datausu ) {
      //alert( "Data Loaded: " + datausu );
      if(datausu ==1 || datausu =="1"){
          $.getJSON("xxxxxxxxxx", function(datos) { 
                   for(i=0;i < datos.length;i++){
                      /* alert(datos[i].cedula);
                       alert(datos[i].nombre);
                       alert(datos[i].apellido);
                       alert(datos[i].celular);
                       alert(datos[i].correo);
                       alert(datos[i].contrasena);*/ 
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('insert into usuario (cedula, nombre, apellido, celular, correo, contrasena) VALUES (?, ?, ? , ?, ?, ?,)',[datos[i].cedula, datos[i].nombre, datos[i].apellido, datos[i].celular, datos[i].correo, datos[i].contrasena])
        },errorGeneric,successGeneric); 

                       }//for

                });
          }//if 

    });

    function errorGeneric(errgeneric) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+errgeneric.message+ " "+errgeneric.code) ;
        console.log(errgeneric.message);
    }

    function successGeneric(tx,sussgene) { 
      alert(sussgene);
        console.log("success!");
    }
```

Comment: First: What is the exact error message? Second: Don't iterate over an event, in this case the transaction. Wait until the transaction is finished and then do the next insert.

Comment: I first make a request to obtain data in JSON, in the success of the petition I iterate the data and then do the insert